# Issue with Springer spbasic

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, journal-publishing

I'm using natbib for an article to be published in a Springer journal.
These are their official [TeX/bibtex styles](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/LaTeX.zip?SGWID=0-0-45-468198-0), which include a tex template and some bibtex/natbib styles.

If I use `[smallextended]{svjour3}` and the `spbasic.bst` style file, adding `natbib` to the header of the file, I get entries without dots after pp and the authors' initials:

> Chevalier J, Mayzlin D (2006) The Effect of Word of Mouth on Sales:
>   Online Book Reviews. Journal of Marketing Research pp 345–354

Instead of

> Chevalier J., Mayzlin D. (2006) The Effect of Word of Mouth on Sales:
>   Online Book Reviews. Journal of Marketing Research, pp. 345–354.

Similarly, I get `et al` in the text instead of `et al.`.
This happens even with a minimal example, adding one entry to the official template.tex.
If I don't add `natbib` to the .tex file, I get even worse results, such as:

> [Chevalier and Mayzlin(2006)] Chevalier J, Mayzlin D (2006) The Effect of 
>   Word of Mouth on Sales: Online Book Reviews. Journal of Marketing Research pp 345–354

I've seen this issue before, but I can't track it down. I'm sure it happens to other authors too.

Any idea?

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know most Springer journals use a style without period after name initials and page abbreviation, and in my experience the Springer editorial staff will edit your bibliography. So I would suggest not to change the style, but if you really want, you can do the following modifcations.

1. Locate `spbasic.bst` in your disk, make a copy, let us say `myspbasic.bst`
2. Use you favourite text editor to edit `myspbasic.bst`
3. Locate `FUNCTION {bbl.pages}` and `FUNCTION {bbl.page}` in the file. They are around line 266 in my copy.
4. change `"pp"` and `"p"` into `"pp."` and `"p."`
5. Locate `FUNCTION {format.names}` (it starts at line 455 in my copy). Change the line `"{vv~}{ll}{ f{}}{ jj}"` to `"{vv~}{ll}{ f.}{ jj}"`, and remove the line `remove.dot`.

Answer (score 4):

To change `et al` to `et al.` :

1. Locate `FUNCTION {bbl.etal}` in `spbasic.bst` (or in the copy of this file, as suggested in [Guido's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75204/3954)).
2. Change `{"et~al"}` to `{"et~al."}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer from both Guido and HelloObamama. 
To add the period at the end. 
Simply locate the following `{fin.entry}` function in the spbasic.bst,

```
FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    'write$
  if$
  newline$
}
```

change them to

```
FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
  write$
  newline$
}
```