# Springer Journal Citation Bibliography weird issue

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, citing, journal

I am preparing a draft (with `twocolumn` as required) in latex for submission to the International Journal of Computer Vision using the template available [here](http://static.springer.com/sgw/documents/468198/application/zip/LaTeX.zip).

In the "*Instructions for authors*" page, "*References*" section [here](http://www.springer.com/computer/image+processing/journal/11263?detailsPage=pltci_2545773), it says

> **Citation**
>
> Cite references in the text by name and year in parentheses. Some examples:
>
> > Negotiation research spans many disciplines (Thompson 1990).
> >     This result was later contradicted by Becker and Seligman (1996).
> >     This effect has been widely studied (Abbott 1991; Barakat et al. 1995; Kelso and Smith 1998; Medvec et al. 1999).
> >      ...
>
> **Reference List**
>   ...
>
> > *Journal article*
> >      Harris, M., Karper, E., Stacks, G., Hoffman, D., DeNiro, R., Cruz, P., et al. (2001). Writing labs and the Hollywood connection. Journal of Film Writing, 44(3), 213–245. 
> >       ...

However, if I try to achieve the above using their template even with a simple example like below:

---

sample.tex:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3} 
\smartqed  
\begin{document}

Now, apple is a tasty fruit \cite{bkey1,bkey2}.

\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

refs.bib:

```
@Article{bkey1,
  author  = {Author1},
  title   = {Title1},
  journal = {Journal1},
  year    = {2016},
}

@Article{bkey2,
  author  = {Author2},
  title   = {Title2},
  journal = {Journal2},
  year    = {2017},
}
```

---

I get this which is far from what the journal asks:
[image: result]

Issues:

1. Parentheses at citations are not coming as asked by the journal.
2. The citation gets through the end of the first column to the second column without a line-break.
3. The references  section is also far from what is asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `spbasic` bibliography style is designed to be used with `natbib`.  So load `natbib` and then use `\citet` for *Author (year)* citations and `\citep` for *(Author, year)* citations.

```
\documentclass[]{svjour3}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@book{Knuth1984texbook,
    Author = {Knuth, D.E.},
    Publisher = {Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts,},
    Title = {The TEXbook, volume A of Computers and typesetting},
    Year = {1984}}

@book{Chomsky1965,
    Address = {Cambridge Mass.},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {{MIT} Press},
    Title = {Aspects of the Theory of Syntax},
    Year = {1965}}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{spbasic}



\begin{document}
\citet[p.4]{Knuth1984texbook} shows that.  Also found here: \citep[p.5]{Chomsky1965} 
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I see my problem. Also, after doing this,  the `et al.` is coming as `et al` without the `stop-mark`.  Any way to solve it?

Comment: Thanks. I have solved the et al issue from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75182/issue-with-springer-spbasic#answer-229613)

Comment: @user62039 That seems to be by design. None of the abbreviations use `.`. This is hard coded in the `.bst` file itself.  (The linked answer is indeed the way to do it, but if you're submitting to the journal, I would leave it as is.)