# Problem with reference including an "et al." with BibTeX bibliographystyle bibstyle

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, journal-publishing

I am writing a paper for Springer and I get some kind of weird reference using BibTeX. Here it an example :

```
\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{filecontents*}{\bib.bib}

@book{pandasAuthor1,
    Author = {Author1, J. and Author2, D. and Author3, R.},
    Publisher = {candies},
    Title = {I like pandas},
    Year = {2051}}
\end{filecontents*}
\bibliographystyle{spbasic}



\begin{document}
\cite{pandasAuthor1} shows that pandas are cute. 
\bibliography{\bib}
\end{document}
```

Result : [Autor1 et al.(2051)Author1, Author2, and Author3]

Why do I get a list of every authors ? How can I get rid of it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from `spbasic.bst`:

> % This bibliography style file is intended for texts in ENGLISH
>   % This is an author-year citation style bibliography. As such, it is
>   % non-standard LaTeX, and requires a special package file to function properly.
>   % Such a package is    natbib.sty   by Patrick W. Daly

If this bibliography style is used in combination with the `natbib` package, one indeed gets the expected output:

```
\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}
\usepackage{filecontents}
%\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}

@book{pandasAuthor1,
    Author = {Author1, J. and Author2, D. and Author3, R.},
    Publisher = {candies},
    Title = {I like pandas},
    Year = {2051}}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\cite{pandasAuthor1} shows that pandas are cute. 

\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Seeing "et al" without a period is a bit disturbing, though...

Comment: This issue can be solve https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380394/171374
However I would not recommand it if you want to submit a paper.

Comment: @moewe Indeed and it is even more confusing as comments in the `.bst` file give example outputs like `Jones et al. (1990)`